# Email font is small when there is a wide image in the email regardless of dynamic width: 100%; height: auto settings

Tags: html, css, image, email, fonts

The text on mobile view in browser, on gmail app or any other app is small.
If i delete the image from my email = font is normal size as expected.

[This is the image itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCl5A.png)

This is the image html in question and i tried viewport and width: 100%; and max-width:100%

```html
<img border=0 width=457 height=auto src="https://picsum.photos/457/200" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_5">
```

Here is the link to HTML and image: [Email HTML and image zip](https://fastupload.io/pCFJbRn4polXYIN/file)

Changed it to

```html
<img border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 457px; height: auto;" src="https://picsum.photos/457/200" alt="Your Alt Text" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_5">
```

as was suggested in [font-size email mobile is too small article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215400/font-size-email-mobile-is-too-small)

still no change, the text is small.. i tried viewport and no change either. maybe i am doing something wrong or something in the other email CSS overrides this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of providing a download link, try to construct a [mre] using a snippet of code and possibly an image you can use online

Comment: Thanks,
The snipets are already there and i added the image itself per your suggestion